# Powershell not going to elseif

Tags: powershell, if-statement, exchange-server

---

The following code doesnt go past the IF statment that has to match Domain1. I don't know how to fix this myself I have been trying for the past 3 days to get this working.

---

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$ExchangeMailboxExport           = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$ExchangeMailboxExport.ClientSize  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$ExchangeMailboxExport.text      = "ExchangeMailboxExport"
$ExchangeMailboxExport.TopMost   = $false
$ExchangeMailboxExport.icon      = "logo.ico"

$Domain                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Domain.multiline                = $false
$Domain.width                    = 368
$Domain.height                   = 20
$Domain.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,34)
$Domain.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Domein                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Domein.text                     = "Domain:"
$Domein.AutoSize                 = $true
$Domein.width                    = 25
$Domein.height                   = 10
$Domein.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,10)
$Domein.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Mailbox                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Mailbox.text                    = "Mailbox:"
$Mailbox.AutoSize                = $true
$Mailbox.width                   = 25
$Mailbox.height                  = 10
$Mailbox.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,59)
$Mailbox.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Postvak                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Postvak.multiline               = $false
$Postvak.width                   = 368
$Postvak.height                  = 20
$Postvak.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13,81)
$Postvak.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$ExportPST                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$ExportPST.text                  = "Export PST"
$ExportPST.width                 = 178
$ExportPST.height                = 30
$ExportPST.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(107,138)
$ExportPST.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$ExportPST.BackColor             = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#00ff21")

$AbortConnection                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$AbortConnection.text            = "Abort Connection"
$AbortConnection.width           = 178
$AbortConnection.height          = 30
$AbortConnection.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(107,183)
$AbortConnection.Font            = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$AbortConnection.BackColor       = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#ff0000") 


$ExchangeMailboxExport.controls.AddRange(@($Domain,$Domein,$Mailbox,$Postvak,$ExportPST,$AbortConnection))

$AbortConnection.Add_Click({ Abort_Connection })
$ExportPST.Add_Click({ Export_PST })

function Export_PST { }
function Abort_Connection { }


#Write your logic code here
function Export_PST {
    if ($Domain.text -eq "Domain1")
    {
        $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri Server1.lan -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
        Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
    }
    elseif ($Domain.text -eq "Domain2")
    {
        $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri Server2.lan -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
        Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
    }
    elseif ($Domain.text -eq "Domain3")
    {
        $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri Server3.lan -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
        Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
        
    }
    elseif ($Domain.text -eq "Domain4") 
    {
        $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri server4.lan -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
        Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
        
    }
}
function Abort_Connection{
    Remove-PSSession $Session
}
[void]$ExchangeMailboxExport.ShowDialog()
```

---

I hope you guys can help me solve this problem because I can't find the solution myself.

---

I have to add more text to post this issue but I dont know what more to add then what I already had

---

```
Connecting to remote server Server1.lan failed with the following error message I get the error above however I filled domain3
```

---

after removing

```
function Export_PST { }
function Abort_Connection { }
```

I stil get the same issue.

Comment: Try adding a `else { Write-Error "Textbox input was not one of the expected values" }` just to confirm the function is actually being run when you click the button

Comment: Please don't use comments for code and error messages. Instead, [update your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67002472/edit) with the additional details :-)

Comment: Remove these lines: `
function Export_PST { }
function Abort_Connection { }
`

Comment: BTW: your function calls may be in another [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1) than the rest of the script. Try to set the variables or the whole function to `global:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way - switch is much more efficient that lots of `ElseIf` statements and unless you need to reuse the function, just wrap it into the `Add_Click`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$ExchangeMailboxExport           = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$ExchangeMailboxExport.ClientSize  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$ExchangeMailboxExport.text      = "ExchangeMailboxExport"
$ExchangeMailboxExport.TopMost   = $false


$Domain                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Domain.multiline                = $false
$Domain.width                    = 368
$Domain.height                   = 20
$Domain.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,34)
$Domain.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Domein                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Domein.text                     = "Domain:"
$Domein.AutoSize                 = $true
$Domein.width                    = 25
$Domein.height                   = 10
$Domein.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,10)
$Domein.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Mailbox                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Mailbox.text                    = "Mailbox:"
$Mailbox.AutoSize                = $true
$Mailbox.width                   = 25
$Mailbox.height                  = 10
$Mailbox.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,59)
$Mailbox.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Postvak                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Postvak.multiline               = $false
$Postvak.width                   = 368
$Postvak.height                  = 20
$Postvak.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13,81)
$Postvak.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$ExportPST                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$ExportPST.text                  = "Export PST"
$ExportPST.width                 = 178
$ExportPST.height                = 30
$ExportPST.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(107,138)
$ExportPST.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$ExportPST.BackColor             = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#00ff21")

$AbortConnection                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$AbortConnection.text            = "Abort Connection"
$AbortConnection.width           = 178
$AbortConnection.height          = 30
$AbortConnection.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(107,183)
$AbortConnection.Font            = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$AbortConnection.BackColor       = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#ff0000") 


$ExchangeMailboxExport.controls.AddRange(@($Domain,$Domein,$Mailbox,$Postvak,$ExportPST,$AbortConnection))

$ExportPST.Add_Click({
    Switch ($Domain.Text) {
        Domain1 {
            Write-Host "Domain1"
            # $Script:Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri Server1.lan -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
            # Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
        }
        Domain2 {
            Write-Host "Domain2"
            #$Script:Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri Server2.lan -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
            # Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
        }
        Domain3 {
            Write-Host "Domain3"
            # $Script:Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri Server3.lan -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
            # Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
        
        }
        Domain4 {
            Write-Host "Domain4"
            # $Script:Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri server4.lan -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
            # Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
        }
    }
})

$AbortConnection.Add_Click({
    Remove-PSSession $Script:Session
})

[void]$ExchangeMailboxExport.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: When using your code I can't use     Remove-PSSession $Session
I get the error Parameter 'ID' is null

Comment: May have to change it to `Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession `

Comment: @Mafklaper In real life, you need to uncomment the lines `$Session = New-PSSession ...` and `Import-PSSession $Session...`, otherwise `$Session` does not exist

Comment: @Theo I did that in my Code but I still get the same error. I tried that at the start

Comment: @Mafklaper I also think you need to put the switch possibilities in quotes, like `Domain4` --> `'Domain4'`. Then in the `$AbortConnection.Add_Click` event put `if ($Session) { Remove-PSSession $Session` }

Comment: @Theo if I add
        if ($Session) { Remove-PSSession $Session | Write-Host Connection stopped  }
        else {Write-Host no session stopped}

I get no session stopped

Comment: @Mafklaper This answer is not mine, but instead of the pipe symbol in `Remove-PSSession $Session | Write-Host` you need a semi-colon `;`. However, if $Session is $null as you first commented, Remove-PSSession obviously throws an error. That is where the test comes in.

Comment: You dont need to put the switch options in quotes - this code works as-is - all oyu need ot do is reintroduce your session code. For anyhting like this I would use Try...Catch and proper error trapping

Comment: Ok - the reason `$session` isn't found is probably because of scoping. You're defining it inside a funciton block therefore it is not available outside of it. See my edit above.